# Sitecore Admin Page login issue

Tags: sitecore-client, admin-pages

I'm having problem with the Sitecore Admin Pages. Once I login to visit a page (e.g., sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx) then I'm currently in the page and I tried to load the page I'm being redirected on the login page even though I did not logged out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66876/discussion-on-question-by-user2543-sitecore-admin-page-login-issue).